# Saving the updated handsontable in r shiny in other variable

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have a handson table which can be like this-
ID REgularCost Sales Margin
1  100         90    10

Now i want a button which will save this table after making appropriate changes. For e.g. if i change regular cost to 110. Then it automatically compute margin to be 20 and display a new updated table with new values. How can i do this in r shiny using handsontable?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is to first make your button running a function. This is possible with the shinyjs package.

first load the package in both Ui.R and Server.R

```
 library(shinyjs)
```

Initialize shinyjs:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
```

then add in the Ui.R a new button

```
        uiOutput("processInt"),
```

Change the initializing code for Server.R to (add the session command)

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
```

In the Server.R you then have defined the button

```
output$processInt <- renderUI({
    actionButton("process","Start")
})
```

Then add the java script functionality to start a function from the button

```
 onclick("process", {
     Results() 
})
```

Now you can call your function that does the change for the table as you want it.

Comment: Thanks Robin. I think i am missing something since i am new to r and r-apps.

Comment: Thanks,can you suggest what is wrong here:UI<-dashboardPage( dashboardSidebar(fileInput("file","Upload")),
dashboardBody(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
actionButton("b1","Get D1"),rHandsontableOutput('D1'), uiOutput("pInt")))))
server<-shinyServer(function(input,output,session){D1<-reactive({
file1<-input$file
read.csv(-code-)
D1<-eventReactive(input$b1,{final<-D1()
#-D1 code-)]})
output$D1<-renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(D1()))
output$pInt<-renderUI({
actionButton("process","Update")})
onclick("process",{Res()})
Res<-function(){bd<-D1()
bd$Margin<-bd$Retail-bd$COST
return(bd)}

Comment: Because of the word restriction...i have restricted it and hence it might look messy...If possible please suggest what can be done